# Add pics from Google Drive to html email body

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api, html-email

Is it possible to add a png / gif file from the google disk to the email htmlbody generated by the google script? I have the code as below, the document is publicly shared, Drive API and Gmail API are enabled.
Is this a problem sharing the file from the disk or an error in my code, please help

```js
function sendaEmail(){
  var templ = HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('template');
  
  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'email@gmail.com',
    subject: "subject",
    htmlBody: message
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#70bbd9" style="padding: 40px 0 30px 0;">
                <img src= <?= DriveApp.getFileById("1tKxUgeX_B27vnpNNpKy1jF_0zOxrBhmL").getAs("image/gif");?> alt="Creating Email" width="300" height="230" style="display: block;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `src` accepts a url or a `cid`  key, both of which are ``string`` type and not a `blob` type. [Read and  practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

yuri's answer is correct but I found a much simpler way. First you change the files sharing settings to 'Anyone with the link' then pull out the file ID and paste here: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILEID. And place the link to html code.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be calling getUrl(), instead of getAs(), getAs() method returns a binary object not an Url, as you should be adding an URL over the src attribute of the HTML  tags.

But, anyway, if you try it, it won't work specifically with the Google Drive links, because the DriveApp Urls are not canonical ones and are not intended to be attached as such on gmail services.

So, how we attach inline image on an email from drive?

The simplest way to do it is as follow:

```
function sendaEmail(){
  var templ = HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('template');
  
  var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();
  
  var imageId = DriveApp.getFileById("YOURIMAGEID");
  var imageBlob = imageId.getBlob();  
  
  MailApp.sendEmail('your@email.com', "Subject",  "Hi", {htmlBody: message, inlineImages: {image: imageBlob}});

}
```

So, what you're doing here is attaching the image object directly, JS will handle this, how? First we have to modify the HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#70bbd9" style="padding: 40px 0 30px 0;">
                <img src= "cid:image" alt="Creating Email" width="300" height="230" style="display: block;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this will do, there are other ways but this is fairly simple.

Here you'll find some info about the several ways for embedding images on emails:
https://blog.mailtrap.io/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/

If you need to add more images, proceed as follow:

```
  var imageId2 = DriveApp.getFileById("15FhCLXu6bQE70iNRCXVAve0TyyoeoUTA");
  var imageBlob2 = imageId2.getBlob(); 
  MailApp.sendEmail('your@email.com', "Subject",  "Hi", {htmlBody: message, inlineImages: {image: imageBlob, image2: imageBlob2}});
```

And now add another  tag on the html

```
    <img src= "cid:image2" alt="Creating Email" style="display: block;" />
```

Comment: It didn't work, the image is attached as an attachment, not as part of the html content like I need

Comment: My bad, it should be cid:image instead of cid:imageBlob, I've updated the code, it will work now.

Comment: thanks it works. Question: how to add more than one image? And if I can ask in this thread how to add an image to a html page in the same way?

Comment: To add more images, declare it and call it, as you did before. I've updated the answer with this info. For the second, is as simply as using the url directly. Ask a new question if desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendImageWithEmail(imageName) {
  var imageName=imageName||'default.png';
  var imgFldrId='folderId';
  var imgs=DriveApp.getFolderById(imgFldrId).getFilesByType(MimeType.PNG);
  while(imgs.hasNext()) {
    var ifile=imgs.next();
    if(ifile.getName()==imageName) {
      var blob=ifile.getBlob();
      var b64Url='data:' + blob.getContentType() + ';base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
      break;
    }
  }
  if(b64Url) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail('email@email.com', 'An Image','' , {htmlBody:Utilities.formatString('<h1>The Image</h1><img src="%s" />',b64Url)});
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Houston. We have a problem');
  }
}
```

This is the original message body:

```
<h1>The Image</h1><img src=3D"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASA=
BIAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQICAQECAQEBAgICA=
gICAgICAQICAgICAgICAgL/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQECAQEBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC=
AgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgL/wAARCABkAGQDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQU=
BAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMU=
EGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTV=
FVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5=
usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQA=
AAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMo=
EIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZ=
GVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbH=
yMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD8l/8Aggr/AMG+a/8=
ABRbTh+1B+1Lq/iHwZ+ynpGvtpfhbwr4an/svxd8b9T0a7Vdeij10gt4W8DQTRSWU1zbqdQu5nn=
FpJYrbxXNz/ch4I/4Ie/8ABILwJ4Z0jwppn7Av7P2uWuj2cNpHqnjbwqfHXie+8pFX7Tq/ifxZd=
3d7qd45G5pJp2yzHAAwB7r/AME9vhf4a+Dv7D/7KXw58HQSW/hvQPgP8NZdMhnO+aKHWvDGn660=
EswGbl45NTePzWO+QRBnO4mvta2twccDPrznv3A9vzFAH5xf8OZ/+CSh6f8ABO/9lLnp/wAWn8O=
E/iBb59aef+CMn/BJbt/wTw/ZSx7/AAm8Of8Axj0x+dfprBZ5GMdPqADk+/XP8vrV8abuA49M8Z=
xkc8+mMUAfl2f+CMn/AASVUc/8E8P2USc4/wCST+Gxg49DB0/Gom/4I1f8Ek1Pzf8ABO/9lMdOR=
8J/Dh5Pbi35NfqJLYbcnGAOT1xn0JHpk/X61kz2gAJ4J5P19+e+D2/QigD80P8AhzZ/wSQPT/gn=
l+ykf+6T+G//AJHo/wCHNn/BJD/pHj+yl/4afw3/API9fopNFs5wRzknsc8Yx9R+H4VADnmgD88=
v+HNn/BJD/pHj+yl/4afw3/8AI9H/AA5s/wCCSH/SPH9lL/w0/hv/AOR6/Q2igD8rPin/AMEIP+=
CPnxZ8I33g/Vv2Fvgx4Rt7xopE174W6bffC/xdYzQyLLHJZeJfBOoWd0i7kAeJ3khkViskTqSK/=
g2/4LVf8EAvGv8AwTZ1y3+JnwU8S658Wf2aPFVzcpo+oa5bWo8beBtRhjNxL4b8TyadFHBq6fZ1=
lltb6CGHzY4ningiljSS6/1HK/Pf/gqb4F8PePv2F/jrY+JLRb2z0fQLXxBbW7AFX1Cx1K1t7Qy=
E/wDLNZLzeQPveWFPBNJ6JvsB/jTkEEgggg4IPBBHUEdjRXuH7R/gm0+Hvxn8deGLDatlaaxPNa=
xqNqww3TGZYgB2GT+dFNapPuB/s6fslsF/Zc/Zp6Z/4UB8G8Z/7J34b6HPByB+dfTVtIvAOM+ue=
vTrntx+tfLf7KBx+y3+zUR/0QH4Of8Aqu/DlfQsc7J1yRnPHpkHuevX+fWgDvraVBjngdT/AI++=
AP8APXZiu0RMYHIAzx36E8fWvOYr8r1Y8cnnBJwccjOOM/lVpdTwD83c5yeegz36ZoA7Oa4Rg2M=
Z6gZ7Ajk+h4/yOawLl0OTngk+/wDe4yB71jvqW7cNw5JIxu69eMdTz+lUJbxnJ5PPXrnrk4z7km=
gCzdMCTjnr2x/e6nHPf64rPPU9qhZix5PGc4ptAFiiq9FAFivij/go1/yZF+0Z/wBiIP8A0+aPX=
2fXxV/wUX/5Mk/aL/7ET/3N6RSls/QD/Io/bW/5OP8AiD/1+Qf+iqKP21v+Tj/iD/1+Qf8Aoqil=
D4I+i/ID/Yu/ZQ/5Na/Zr/7ID8HP/Vd+HK9+r57/AGUSf+GXP2bOT/yQL4O9z/0Tvw5XvuT6n8z=
VAT0VBk+p/M0ZPqfzNAE+B6V5/wDEH4sfCz4S6dbax8VfiX8P/hnpN5K8FnqnxB8ZeHPBmnXc8Q=
RpYba98R6lbRTyqJIyyqxIDjIGRXJ/tEfGKw/Z/wDgV8WvjXqlm+qWvwx8A+JfGCaSkphfWb/SN=
Nnn0rRUm/5YNeaoLO2Eh4Q3W88A1/m0fH/4o/GD9p/4neIvi78a/F2seNPGXiO8nuHuNQuZW07R=
bGSZ5bXQPDWltKYdA8OWqOI7aztlSKJFzhnZ3b4LjXjnD8IrC0I4X67j8YpSjBy5IQhFpc83Zt8=
zuoxS15ZNyjZX/rT6MX0Vs2+kNUz3NK+e/wCrPCnDtSnQq4iFD6xiMRiqsPaLD4em6lOEFTp8tS=
tVqSfL7SlGFKpzzlS/01/Bfj3wL8SNDh8T/Dvxp4T8e+GriSSG38Q+C/Eej+KdDnmi2+bFDq2h3=
k9vLIu5dyrISu4ZAzXWV/mv/sM/tRfFr9hv45+GPin8PdZ1mPwy+q6Za/E/wHDdyf2D8QvBP2tB=
rGj6lpskwgfVksXun0y9ZfOsLzZNG2wzRS/6Rel6naazpmnaxp0/2jT9VsbTUrG4AZRPZ31vHdW=
swVgCoaCVGwRkbua6OC+MsPxdhcTOOH+qYzBOKq0+bmjaafJOErJtS5ZJpq8WrNtNN+N9Jj6Nmc=
fR3z3JMPVzhcRcN8UU688DjPY/V6qqYZ0vrGGxFFTqxjUpKvRlGpCbhWhUuowlGcI6tFQZPqfzN=
GT6n8zX2p/MhPXxV/wUX/5Mk/aL/wCxE/8Ac3pFfZ2T6n8zXxZ/wUVJ/wCGJf2iuT/yIh7/APUa=
0ilLZ+gH+Rb+2t/ycf8AEH/r8g/9FUUftrf8nH/EH/r8g/8ARVFKHwR9F+QH+xP+yj/ya5+zZ/2=
QL4O/+q78OV77Xz5+ymT/AMMu/s28n/kgfwd7n/onnh2vfMn1P5mqAnoqDJ9T+ZoyfU/maAPMvj=
j8IdA+Pvwf+JPwW8UXc2naH8TfB+t+ELzVbeNZrjRn1ezkt7PW7eBztuJ7K+NtdJG2Fka0CMQGN=
fwE/Hj9k/4o/s2fErX/AIVfF3wle+GvFGhXMyRPLBO2j+IdLE0sVl4l8Laq8Kx694bu0iL213Dl=
WGY5BHPHLEn+iHk+p/M1neJ9B8I+PNDi8MfEfwJ4D+J3hqCUXFt4f+I/g/QfGuj204xia3sNfsp=
kikGBggcY4xX57x1wHR4whha9LGfUMxwSlGM3DnhOEnzck0nFq0ruMot25pJxldW/sH6Kf0scw+=
jhis9yzH8Of63cG8SzpVq+GhXWGxOFxVKPs/rWFqSp1ac/aUuWnXoVYxVT2VGUK1F05Kr/AARfs=
X/sHfED9sX4y+H/AIfeFtI1O18GWepabffFTx/HaOuj+APBAuRJq+p3OoTQNAdfmsILyPSLFz5l=
/fBIgqwLcTQ/306dp1lpGn2Ok6bALbTtLs7XTtPtwxYW9lZQJbWsAY8sEgijXJ67aTSbPRvDeg2=
fhPwf4b8MeB/CWnEtYeFPBPh/S/C3hyzZjljb6Ro1tFDGSQDwuMjIANTZPqfzNdPA/BVDg7B4mH=
1p47HY5xdWry8kbQT5IQjzSajHmk3Ju827tJJRXifSl+k5mn0kOI8lxUchjwtwrwtTr08vwPtvr=
NZzxLpfWcVia6p0oyq1lQoRjShTVOhCmoRlUlKpVqT0VBk+p/M0ZPqfzNfcn8sk9fFn/BRX/kyX=
9or/ALEQ/wDp60ivszJ9T+Zr4u/4KJEn9if9onJP/IiHv/1GtJpS2foB/kZ/trf8nH/EH/r8g/8=
ARVFH7a3/ACcf8Qf+vyD/ANFUUofBH0X5Af7EH7Kf/Jrv7Nv/AGQP4O/+q88O175Xz7+yoT/wy9=
+zdyf+SCfB7uf+ieeHa97yfU/maoCeioMn1P5mjJ9T+ZoAnoqDJ9T+ZoyfU/maAJ6KgyfU/maMn=
1P5mgCeioQWJwCcngcmuj03TTMoJySSSefbgj9f1oAwvrkZ9QQfyNfF3/BRL/kyf9on/sRD/wCn=
rSa++rvStkeSMZB468Z6Y+uf84r4E/4KKo8X7Fn7RSMSceBGxnOCP7Z0n35pS2foB/ka/trf8nH=
/ABB/6/IP/RVFH7a3/Jx/xB/6/IP/AEVRSh8EfRfkB/rw/sH/ABC8NfFL9jP9mTxr4QvF1Dw7f/=
BjwJpmnahGyvDfr4Y0O18LXF/auhIksp7vRZ5YH/jhmjfjdivrOv8ANp/4Ief8HCkv7CvhS0/Zd=
/amttb8Sfs+x3hl8DePdIsTrXiH4WtLtEunanptuv2vX/CXkoqRLD9purNYLa2toBaR7U/tD+H/=
APwV1/Yt+KHh/T/E3gn9oj4Watpmp20V1Aj69Bp+pQpKgcR32kaiIrqwuADho5okdSCCM1QH6p0=
V+dP/AA8n/Zm/6LT8Nf8AwobH/wCOUn/Dyn9mUf8ANafht/4UFkf5PSuu6A/ReivznP8AwUq/Zk=
H/ADWn4b/+D60P8mpv/Dyv9mQf81o+HP8A4PLU/wAmouu6A/Rqivzk/wCHln7Mf/RaPh1/4O7f/=
Gk/4eXfsx/9Fo+Hf/g5gouu6A/R5Dh0JxgMCcnH8++fp9a9A0e4iUJnp1x7DjgDry3p2r8oP+Hl=
/wCzEP8Ams/w8/8ABxF/hWhaf8FPv2YoBtf4z/D8gdxq6EkehG3jr2z68UXXdAfrDqt1C8ZwAvH=
IyCOwzn09frX5j/8ABTjxRo/h79jf40Q6rcpaf8JNocfhnTJJCFjk1e6uF1GztmY4+eUaVNEnXM=
sqL3rgvFX/AAVg/Zb0PS7jUm+KvhrV/JXIstCNxq+pTtwAsFrbR5Y5xyzKoHJYV/Lb/wAFdv8Ag=
s7pHxP0qXRtNvItI8J6ELg+FPBcF1bz6z4g1p1Maa54h+yMRFGHEbRW5YxxLDESvnK8jzKStZat=
/MTfbc/kY/bQnhuf2jPiFJBIkqC+iQsjBgHSPDKSD1B60V88+KvEeoeL/EeteJtVkMl/reoXOoX=
LEk4e4kL7QSegBA/CiqSskuwzn66LQvF3ijwxKZvD2v6ro0hBBNhez24IPX5EfGfwoopgdd/wuv=
4tf9FD8Vf+Da4/+Ko/4XX8Wv8Aoofir/wbXH/xVFFKy7AH/C6/i1/0UPxV/wCDa4/+Ko/4XX8Wv=
+ih+Kv/AAbXH/xVFFFl2AP+F1/Fr/oofir/AMG1x/8AFUf8Lr+LX/RQ/FX/AINrj/4qiiiy7AH/=
AAuv4tf9FD8Vf+Da4/8AiqP+F1/Fr/oofir/AMG1x/8AFUUUWXYBD8aviywIPxC8VEEYIOq3HIP=
/AAKvP9S1XUtYuXvNVv7vUbqRiz3F5cS3ErFjk/NKxwM9hxRRTsuwFCiiigD/2Q=3D=3D" />
```

It displays at comcast.net but not on Gmail.  I don't know why? Sorry

Comment: the image does not load into the email

Comment: It loaded for me.

Comment: ok, so what am I doing wrong? I add folder ID and instead default.png I add my file's name, right? And of course change email and run function sendImageWithEmail

Comment: I sent it to a comcast.net account and it displayed there but I guess Google Emails don't display the dataUrls.  I looked at the original email and it is in fact there.  I'll just delete the answer if you wish.